# Working out a percentage group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm essentially trying to work out which percentage value (e.g. 1 to 100) a range of numbers fall into.

For example, if I have a simple table of 500 records:

```
declare @temp table (id int, percentage int)

insert @temp (id)
select Number
from master..spt_values
where type = 'p' 
and number between 1 and 500

select * from @temp
```

Then I'd like to work out that the first 1% of the records (i.e. those with id 1 to 5) will be be percentage number 1, the second 1% of records (i.e. those with id 6 to 10) will be number 2 etc.

I'm seen that some of the more recent versions on sql server have some percentage based functions like PERCENTILE and PERCENT_RANK which I think might have been a possibility, however I'm using SQL Server 2005 so not sure if my options are limited?

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: NTILE(100) might be good enough for what you are trying to do.  that command goes back to 2005

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with a number of rows like 502, the first 2 percentage groups of data will include the "extra" row:

```
declare @temp table (id int, percentage int)

insert @temp (id, percentage)
select 
  Number, 
  ntile(100) over (order by number)
from master..spt_values
where type = 'p' 
and number between 1 and 500

select * from @temp
```

Result:

```
id  percentage
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   2
7   2
8   2
9   2
10  2
11  3
..  ..
..  ..
```

Comment: @ca8msm changed my answer to include [NTILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(NTILE_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) instead. Seems better

Comment: Ah yes that looks a lot neater!